# Return partial View if model state was not valid

Tags: asp.net, return, partial-views, partial

I have a slider that has a  registration form, I create the form as a partial View .
this is the method of create registration form:
Get method:

```
       public IActionResult CorporationRegisterRequest()
   {

       CorporationRequestViewModel corporationViewModel = new CorporationRequestViewModel();
       return PartialView("CorporationRegisterPartial", corporationViewModel);
   }
```

Post Method

```
    [HttpPost()]
    [Route("CorporationRegister")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CorporationRegisterRequest(CorporationRequestViewModel corporationRequestViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _userService.CreateCorporationRequest(corporationRequestViewModel);


            switch (result)
            {
                case CorporationRequestResult.Failed:
                    TempData[ErrorMessage] = "NotFound";
                    break;

                case CorporationRequestResult.UserHasNotRequestWithThisNumber:
                    TempData[WarningMessage] = "User Has no Request with this Number";
                    break;

                case CorporationRequestResult.Successfully:
                    TempData[SuccessMessage] = "Your Request send, Our Staff Calling You As soon As Possible";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }


        return                         return PartialView("CorporationRegisterPartial", corporationRequestViewModel);
```

'

If model was valid , every thing is ok and add to database. But if Model state is not valid, it had to return to index page , index includes that partial
how can I return to partial ? I have the problem in last return in my method, that shows "corporationRequestViewModel" and index at same time if not valid model

@Mikhail I use this code first , but when is not valid , it returns just view of partial view , without any style of that page and without index, I want to return to home page and show the partial view, I update the question and add the picture of return partial

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7inh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can return it using the PartialView result (like you do it in the above GET method) + pass the bound Model instance (from action method argument) as a parameter (to keep / visualize model state errors):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CorporationRegisterRequest(CorporationRequestViewModel corporationRequestViewModel) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        ...
    }

    //return RedirectToAction("CorporationRegisterRequest", PartialView("CorporationRegisterPartial", corporationRequestViewModel));
    return PartialView("CorporationRegisterPartial", corporationRequestViewModel);
}
```

However, it seems to be valid if you do an async POST request. Otherwise, you may need to return the entire View result and transfer model Model instance instead of creating a new instance, for example, using a TempData.

Comment: I use this code first , but when is not valid , it returns just view of partial view , without any style of that page and without index, I want to return to home page and show the partial view, I update the question and add the picture of return partial.it  is part of index , tha is partial here